# Render Piecharts on Google Map

Tags: javascript

Using javascript + GoogleMaps

In my app, I have a screen where a Google Map is rendered. And, I have some statistics of Population growth across the countries which are rendered as PieCharts. I succeeded in rendering PieCharts using Google API.
Now I want to render these generated PieCharts on GoogleMap. For example, there should be a PieChart rendered over America which explains the population growth yearly in America. How can I achieve it? Plz sujjest some idea. Is it possible using Google API for Map Layers.?? Thanks for the patience.

Answer (score 0):

depends on the API, i.e. v3 you could use view overlays ( read https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=de#OverlayView ) allowing to append custom DOM elements, where you can render whatever HTML you might want to. In that view you can render SVG / VML piecharts generated by whatever 3rd party chart library you use.